# Making sure floats in binary file are represented as expected on different platforms?

Tags: c++, caching, floating-point, endianness

I have a large list of floating point numbers stored in a file as text in the following format

```
0.0010245  0.4624603  1.326266  -5.203623
```

The numbers are written out as plain text, then parsed to actual floating points as it's read into the program.

What I would like to do is cache the float representation of 4 bytes, store this as a seperate binary file, and then use it instead of the original plain text one on subsequent runs of the program.  However, I need to make sure the endianness and format of the platform didn't change between runs (if the user upgrades, moves files, or just changes computers).

So I have a test float written to the header of the cached file.  It has stored the 4 byte binary representation of `-50.50505050` (just a random magic number).  If the value of the representation in the file matches (within a small error) what the program says it should be, it will use the cached file.  If it is not, it will use the original and regenerate another cached file.

My question is, is this test good enough to ensure the format and endianness of the cached file is correct always?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define the standard for your file. I.e. say that it's always little-endian and 32-bit IEEE float. If your target platform's native representation differs from that then perform the conversion upon read of the file to the native format.

Note that this is an issue only if you share the file between computers (or upgrades like you mentioned). If you always run it on the same configuration, you don't need to worry about the conversion and always just store the native format.

Comment: Since the value is multi-byte, you should put into your standard the Endianness that created it.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems reasonable.  I cannot think of a pair of platforms where you'd get a false positive by moving such a file generated on one platform to the other.

I would avoid the "within a small error" bit, though.  Check that you got **exactly** the number you expected.  That means you should check for `==`.  No arithmetic is occurring, so you will get exactly the number you serialised unless something weird happened, in which case you want to fail over.

Comment: How does this port to platforms that don't have the same endianness?  For example, if your computer is Big Endian and you write to the file and I read the file on my Little Endian platform, what will happen?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: You get the wrong number and you read the text file, exactly as OP wanted.

Comment: “Check that you got exactly the number you expected” Since the goal is source-code portability though, testing with `==` may require extra care. Say that the C99-compliant compiler defines FLT_EVAL_METHOD to 1 or 2. Then `if (float_read_from_file == -50.50505050f)` will fail because the floating-point literal is stored with double (resp. long double) precision. Testing exact equality is more elegant but requires writing exactly the expected number (hexadecimal is one possibility, picking a value with a short exact decimal representation as sentinel is another).

Comment: Or casting: `if (float_read_from_file == (float)-50.50505050f)`.